# Raspberry pi:send email when PULLED UP switch is pressed

Tags: python, windows, raspberry-pi, putty

i have created python script mail.py which include code of sending mail when gpio 4 is pressed..my gpio 4 is PULLED UP switch ,but problem is that when i directly run the script it runs means it send mail but when i press that switch it doesn't run before pressing switch it goes outside the loop and script doen't run,also email doesn't send..i have also put delay for that..i think problem is when i press the switch one time it have to store the state of switch so after 10 second it read the state but i can't store the state of switch..if any suggestion plz tell me..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do, but is seems to me you want this script to run until the button is pressed and then send a mail once?

Something along the line of `GPIO.wait_for_edge(4, GPIO.FALLING)` is what would be easiest to fit into your code, such as:

```
try:  
    GPIO.wait_for_edge(4, GPIO.FALLING)
    # Create email
    ...
except KeyboardInterrupt:  
    GPIO.cleanup()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

However, you may want to send a mail every time the button is pressed? If so it is even better to use a callback function using GPIO.add_event_detect. In that case this is more suitable:

```
# Create and send mail
def send_mail():
    ...

# add rising edge detection on a channel, ignoring further edges 
# for 200ms for switch bounce handling
GPIO.add_event_detect(channel, GPIO.FALLING, callback = send_mail, bouncetime = 200)
```

For more details on RPi.GPIO input, refer to: https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/

Comment: thank u but this is not work for me...plz give me another solution...my switch is bydefult 1 when i press it goes into 0 state...so what's the solution to save the state...can u plz give me full example what i have to exactly write in the code.

Comment: Based on my example and the link I included you should be able to find a fitting solution for your particular need. If you want to save the state you may want to keep track of the input by listening in on RISING as well as FALLING events.

Comment: thank u..i refered that link..and i understand what u have said ..but that is not my problem..in my case once switch is pressed ,it will release.i m not pressing continuous so after some time when it will release it understood that switch is not pressed even single time..so i need to save state of switch right after i pressed the switch so from that saved state i should be able to send mail so simple is that,that released switch doesn't have to impact on pressed switch state.

Answer (score 0):

## you can write the listener inside a loop and also the mail functionality as function

## like

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:

if(GPIO.input(23) ==1):

## # button pressed then cal the mail() function

## #after excutting the function if need you can again set the pinpoint back to 0

if(GPIO.input(24) == 0):

print(“Button 2 pressed”)

GPIO.cleanup()

try the example

Comment: Hey let me know why you un-vote the answer?  its doesn't work for you ?